# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extras' error executing Github Actions workflow for Pytest

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest, github-actions

When I run from GitHub Action always I get this error...

```
Run pytest -rA
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.9.16, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /home/runner/work/Githubpytest/Githubpytest
collected 1 item

safetyNetwebTestcases/ActionPlan/test_001CreateIssue.py 
INTERNALERROR> Traceback (most recent call last):
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 270, in wrap_session
INTERNALERROR>     session.exitstatus = doit(config, session) or 0
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 324, in _main
INTERNALERROR>     config.hook.pytest_runtestloop(session=session)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 60, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/main.py", line 349, in pytest_runtestloop
INTERNALERROR>     item.config.hook.pytest_runtest_protocol(item=item, nextitem=nextitem)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 60, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     return outcome.get_result()
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_result.py", line 60, in get_result
INTERNALERROR>     raise ex[1].with_traceback(ex[2])
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 39, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     res = hook_impl.function(*args)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 112, in pytest_runtest_protocol
INTERNALERROR>     runtestprotocol(item, nextitem=nextitem)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 125, in runtestprotocol
INTERNALERROR>     rep = call_and_report(item, "setup", log)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_pytest/runner.py", line 222, in call_and_report
INTERNALERROR>     report: TestReport = hook.pytest_runtest_makereport(item=item, call=call)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_hooks.py", line 265, in __call__
INTERNALERROR>     return self._hookexec(self.name, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_manager.py", line 80, in _hookexec
INTERNALERROR>     return self._inner_hookexec(hook_name, methods, kwargs, firstresult)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.16/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pluggy/_callers.py", line 55, in _multicall
INTERNALERROR>     gen.send(outcome)
INTERNALERROR>   File "/home/runner/work/Githubpytest/Githubpytest/safetyNetwebTestcases/conftest.py", line 56, in pytest_runtest_makereport
INTERNALERROR>     extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html(html))
INTERNALERROR> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extras'

============================= 5 warnings in 6.01s ==============================
Error: Process completed with exit code 3.
```

Comment: Update the question with your code trials.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The main error is:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extras'
```

which implies you are trying to retrive a property *`extras`* on a object, which is currently *`NULL`*

Before you attempt to retrive a property *`extras`* ensure the reference contains the desired object but not *`NULL`*